# Neural network to detect connected parameters

Tags: neural-networks

I have a list of configurations. Each configuration contains a number of parameters. The parameters have the same name but sometimes different values.
I now want a neural network, that can detect, which Parameters always have the same value when Parameter 1 has value 'A'. 
I want to find out which Parameters are "related", so which parameters always change together and have always the same pair of values.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy.  Find all configurations where parameter 1 has value A; throw away all the rest.  Now you can easily test whether all the remaining parameters have the same value for parameter 2 (just scan through them and see if they all have the same value as the first); you can do that for parameter 3; and so on.  No fancy algorithm is needed -- it's straightforward to program with a simple linear scan.